# Comparing Worksheet name in vba excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to compare a name with worksheets that already exist to see if it has been created or not yet.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim Ldate As String
    Dim Lweekday As Integer
    Dim Newweek As String
    Dim Sname As String

    Ldate = Date
    Lweekday = Weekday(Ldate)

    If Lweekday = 1 Then
        Newweek = DateAdd("d", 3, Ldate)
        Sname = Month(Newweek) & "-" & Day(Newweek) & "-" & Year(Newweek)
        Sheets.Add.Name = Sname
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Worksheets("Template").Select
        Range("A1:A2").Copy
        Worksheets(Sname).Select
        Range("A1").PasteSpecial
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

     End If    
End Sub
```

Basically I want to check if the worksheet has been created and if it has then exit the code, if not then copy and paste a template in the worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a function to check that.

```
Private Function IsWorksheetExist(sName As String) As Boolean
    Dim oWS As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sName)
    If oWS Is Nothing Then
        IsWorksheetExist = False
    Else
        IsWorksheetExist = True
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```